# An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i dont undestand what wrong. I tried to make a simple web app for work whis Data Base(i use MySQL 8.0.28.0 and asp.net with MVC ) This is the error text <An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Configuration value 'Server=localhost;Database=Ocjetpes;User=root;Password=' is not supported.
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728>used](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%3Eused) this command Add-Migration InitialMigration.this is Employee.cs

```
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Ocjetpes.Models
{
[Index(nameof(ModelCode), IsUnique = true)]
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="name field is required")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:100,MinimumLength =2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "name field is required")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "name field is required")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 20, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Sost { get; set; }
}
}
```

``
this ApplicationDbContext.cs
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace Ocjetpes.Data
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{ }
public DbSet Employees { get; set; }
}
}
`

this program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var connectionString= builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

i tried to found error in MySQL but server is working and i create a new local server and added new db but error is still not solved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mmm, seems like the problem could be in your config - can you post that?